# error deploying react project with font-awesome import

Tags: css, reactjs, import, font-awesome, parse-error

I'm trying to `npm run deploy` on my project where I'm storing the minified font-awesome css file and I'm getting the following error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/assets/css/font-awesome.all.min.css
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 30
```

The app works fine on development sever.
The error shows whether I'm importing the css to the main css file or the main js file.

I only found some related old posts with potential solutions for a next.js project and yarn like in this link: https://github.com/vercel/next-plugins/issues/310

This is a react project and I'm using npm.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on this unless there's more information regarding module-bundler and what is the configuration for the same. As it's treated differently according to module-bundler.

I would suggest you to use official package of fontawesome for react [@fortawesome/react-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome)

PS. Module Bundler configuration should not be changed without proper knowledge as it can make whole application crash.